# Slicer for multiple pivot with different data source Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Helllo

Is there a way I can use a slicer to filter multiple pivot with 3 different data sources. Thanks.

Comment: Short answer is yes as long as you have to filter a common field name (e.g. all data source have `WorkWeek` field). Long answer depends on your specific issue once you've tried something to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Just Double Click on the Slicer and then go to Options, then go PivotTableConnections, then select the check box which you want to connect and click on OK.

Here are some snaps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I guess this covers your requirement :)